# Entity Framework instance of entity type cannot be tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following entities and context with Entity Framework Core 1.1:

```
public class Language {
  public String LanguageCode { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<LanguageI18N> LanguagesI18N { get; set; } = new List<LanguageI18N>();
}

public class LanguageI18N {
  public String LanguageCode { get; set; }
  public String TranslationCode { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }        
  public virtual Language Language { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext {

  public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
  public DbSet<LanguageI18N> LanguagesI18N { get; set; }

  public Context(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {

    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<Language>(b => {
      b.ToTable("Languages");
      b.HasKey(x => x.LanguageCode);
      b.Property(x => x.LanguageCode).IsRequired(true).HasMaxLength(2).ValueGeneratedNever();        
    });

    builder.Entity<LanguageI18N>(b => {
      b.ToTable("LanguagesI18N");
      b.HasKey(x => new { x.LanguageCode, x.TranslationCode });      
      b.Property(x => x.LanguageCode).HasMaxLength(2).IsRequired(true);
      b.Property(x => x.TranslationCode).HasMaxLength(2).IsRequired(true);
      b.HasOne(x => x.Language).WithMany(x => x.LanguagesI18N).HasForeignKey(x => x.LanguageCode).IsRequired(true).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
      b.HasOne(x => x.Language).WithMany(x => x.LanguagesI18N).HasForeignKey(x => x.TranslationCode).IsRequired(true).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);      
    });      

  }

}
```

Then I created a Language with translations for its names as follows:

```
public class Program {

  public static void Main(String[] args) {

    DbContextOptionsBuilder builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>();

    builder.UseInMemoryDatabase();

    using (Context context = new Context(builder.Options)) {

      Language language = new Language { LanguageCode = "en" };

      language.LanguagesI18N.Add(new LanguageI18N { LanguageCode = "en", TranslationCode = "en", Name = "English" });
      language.LanguagesI18N.Add(new LanguageI18N { LanguageCode = "en", TranslationCode = "pt", Name = "Inglês" });

      context.Languages.Add(language);

      context.SaveChanges();

    }         

  }

}
```

I am creating a language with code "en" and translations for its name in English and Portuguese.

When I run the code I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: 
>       The instance of entity type 'LanguageI18N' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked. 
>       When adding new entities, for most key types a unique temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if the key property is assigned the default value for its type). 
>       If you are explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other new entities.
>       When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

The code works with InMemoryDatabase and the change suggested by Ivan Stoev:

```
b.HasOne<Language>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.TranslationCode).IsRequired(true).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

But when I replaced InMemoryDatabase:

```
builder.UseInMemoryDatabase();
```

By SQL Server database:

```
  builder.UseSqlServer(yourConnectionString);
```

I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 
An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_LanguagesI18N_Languages_TranslationCode". 
The conflict occurred in database "TestDb", table "dbo.Languages", column 'LanguageCode'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Any idea why?

Comment: How are you creating your context object? Is it being injected? How have you added it to your DI container?

Comment: I just create the Context with a connection string in a console application and it is running fine because I am able to get the count of Languages table.

Comment: So you do `var context = new Context();` somewhere? (PS naming your context class Context is confusing!)

Comment: Yes, I am ... I am using Context as type because at the moment I am just testing this.

Comment: I'm having trouble to understand your code because you are obviously cutting out bits to post here, but in doing that you have provided code that does not compile. For example `language.LanguagesI18N` will give you a null reference exception. There are other issues too. Can you provide a [mcve]

Comment: I just added the Context instance and a LanguageI18N collection initializer in Language entity. Those were the things missing. Can you replicate now?

Comment: That's just one of the issues. I see at least 2 more: `Context` doesn't have a parameterless constructor and `x.HasKey(x => x.LanguageCode)` is a compile error too.

Comment: @DavidG I just edit my code and now you have full functional code using a InMemoryContext so no need for SQL Server and I get the same exception. Does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
b.HasOne(x => x.Language).WithMany(x => x.LanguagesI18N).HasForeignKey(x => x.LanguageCode).IsRequired(true).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
b.HasOne(x => x.Language).WithMany(x => x.LanguagesI18N).HasForeignKey(x => x.TranslationCode).IsRequired(true).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

you are trying to map one and the same association represented by the `Language` -> `LanguagesI18N` navigation properties to two different FKs (`LanguageCode` and `TranslationCode`), which is not possible. The second line effectively overwrites the first, leading to incorrect setup.

Since you have two `one-to-many` relationships, and assuming the first line contains the correct setup for the first, the second can be setup by changing the last line to:

```
b.HasOne<Language>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.TranslationCode).IsRequired(true).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Such setup (w/o navigation property at both sides) was not possible in EF6, but perfectly supported in EF Core thanks to the parameterless overloads of the `HasOne` / `HasMany` methods. Just keep them (as well as `WithOne` / `WithMany`) in sync with your model navigation properties.

Comment: Your suggestion only works with InMemoryDatabase not with real SQL database ... At least it seems that way. I added an Update to my questions explaining what I tried.

Comment: Actually the new exception indicates that the above works - a correct FK constraint has been created. And now violated by your insert, which means you have specified `TranslationCode` which doesn't exist in the `Language` table, do you?

Comment: @IvanStoev is right here. The language code `pt` is not added to language table therefore you cannot add a child referencing it specifically for required relationships.